# YouTube API causing "an error occurred" message on IE9 and IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

Basically I'm using YouTube API and when you click on the first video in the library, it plays fine, when the second thumbnail is clicked, however, I'm receiving "an error occurred" message. It's as if the video didn't exit. It works fine on IE11 and all other browsers.

```js
(function () {

   $('#video-navbar').slick({
        arrows: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 3.3
    });

   $('.video-slide').click(function () {
      var item = $(this);
      item.parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      item.addClass('selected');
      var videoId = item.data('video');
      tipsVideoData = item.data('ga-data');
      tipsPlayer.cueVideoById(videoId);
      tipsPlayerStarted = false;
      tipsPlayer.playVideo();
   });

});

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var commercialPlayer, commercialPlayerStarted = false;
var tipsPlayer, tipsPlayerStarted = false, tipsVideoData;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

   tipsVideoData = { "category": "Custom", "action": "How-To-Videos", "label": "Intro-to-Potatoes" };
   tipsPlayer = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '205',
      width: '365',
      videoId: 'vA3smKNBGUQ',
      playerVars: {
         modestbranding: 1,
         rel: 0,
         showinfo: 0
      },
      events: {
         onStateChange: function (event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !tipsPlayerStarted) {
               tipsPlayerStarted = true;
               UDM.evq.push(['trackEvent', tipsVideoData.category, tipsVideoData.action, 'Play-' + tipsVideoData.label]);
            } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
               tipsPlayerStarted = false;
               UDM.evq.push(['trackEvent', tipsVideoData.category, tipsVideoData.action, 'Completed-' + tipsVideoData.label]);
            }
         }
      }
   });
}
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
       
<div id="video-navbar">
    <div id="Redwood-video1" class="video-slide" data-video="vA3smKNBGUQ"
      data-ga-event='{"category":"see-whats-new", "action":"video", "label":"farmers-market"}'>
        <div class="Redwood-playBtn"><img src="img/videoHover.png" alt="I Can’t Believe It’s Not Butter! Video-Play"></div>
        <div class="Redwood-videoTitle">Farmer's Market</div>
    </div>

    <div id="Redwood-video2" class="video-slide" data-video="SEKIre0wH_8"
      data-ga-event='{"category":"see-whats-new", "action":"video", "label":"hey-muffin"}'>
        <div class="Redwood-playBtn"><img src="img/videoHover.png" alt="I Can’t Believe It’s Not Butter! Video-Play"></div>
        <div class="Redwood-videoTitle">Hey Muffin</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Redwood-video3" class="video-slide" data-video="17SbQ9BlyGM"
      data-ga-event='{"category":"see-whats-new", "action":"video", "label":"frenchman"}'>
        <div class="Redwood-playBtn"><img src="img/videoHover.png" alt="I Can’t Believe It’s Not Butter! Video-Play"></div>
        <div class="Redwood-videoTitle">Frenchman</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Redwood-video4" class="video-slide" data-video="O-4pArq9Tnk"
      data-ga-event='{"category":"see-whats-new", "action":"video", "label":"shocked"}'>
        <div class="Redwood-playBtn"><img src="img/videoHover.png" alt="I Can’t Believe It’s Not Butter! Video-Play"></div>
        <div class="Redwood-videoTitle">Shocked</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Redwood-video5" class="video-slide" data-video="DnVv2ZkiNGo"
      data-ga-event='{"category":"see-whats-new", "action":"video", "label":"turkey-time"}'>
        <div class="Redwood-playBtn"><img src="img/videoHover.png" alt="I Can’t Believe It’s Not Butter! Video-Play"></div>
        <div class="Redwood-videoTitle">Turkey Time</div>
    </div>

    <div id="Redwood-video6" class="video-slide" data-video="N5sPT12O5YU"
      data-ga-event='{"category":"see-whats-new", "action":"video", "label":"lobstah"}'>
        <div class="Redwood-playBtn"><img src="img/videoHover.png" alt="I Can’t Believe It’s Not Butter! Video-Play"></div>
        <div class="Redwood-videoTitle">Lobstah</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What line “an error occurred” message is pointed on?

Comment: The video itself returns that message. Instead of playing the video, it's a black background with youTube's "an error occurred" message. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Having this error as well.